# Control inrush current

Tags: pmos, inrush-current

A basic question, how does the P-Mosfet reduce the inrush current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqmK0s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[Old image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZPXP.png)

Can the P-Mosfet's drain and source orientation be swapped along with the diode and would that cause any changes to the protection.

Please help.

http://archive.eetasia.com/www.eetasia.com/ARTICLES/2001JUL/2001JUL03_AMD_POW_TAC.PDF%3FSOURCES%3DDOWNLOAD

Comment: eek..my eyes...

Comment: @Trevor: The image really is that bad in the PDF!

Answer (score 4):

Surge is reduced by using a constant current source to charge the Gate capacitance of the P-FET. 
You can alter the amount of time taken in the linear region by altering the CC drive. 
If you drive the P-FET with a fast drive (high current therefore fast voltage change) you would get surge current.

No you can't turn the P-Fet around (swap Source and Drain) since you'd have simply a (body) diode which would conduct and drop the source voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can we connect the gate directly to the ground instead of CC circuitry? Would that help in reducing the inrush current?

Comment: No, that would defeat the surge protection. Read the note you reference .....this is slew rate control of a FET turn-on.

Answer (score 0):

As Trevor says, that's not a nice image to look at!

Quick answer to your question though: the FET slowly turns on, basically acting as a resistor that reduces in value. High resistance at the start reducing the high currents when you pretty much have a short to ground as the capacitor is empty. The FET turns on, reducing resistance as the voltage of the cap increases to match the source voltage.

Answer (score 0):

It should be obvious that if you swap drain and source, the body diode will no longer block the inrush current.